# Preserving concatenated elements in a Python str to list conversion

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I was wondering if there was a particular method that would allow me to take a list element (`["3D"]`) and, using a for loop, nest it within another list (`[["3D"]]`) while avoiding the current type-conversion problem I'm having which results in `[["3","D"]]`.

I've included the following for clarity;

```
hand = ["3D", "4D", "4C", "5D", "JS", "JC"]

from itertools import groupby 

def generate_plays(hand):
    plays = []
    for rank,suit in groupby(hand, lambda f: f[0]):
        plays.append(list(suit))
    for card in hand:
        if card not in plays:       #redundant due to list nesting
            plays.append(list(card))       #problematic code in question
    return plays
```

output:

```
[['3D'], ['4D', '4C'], ['5D'], ['JS', 'JC'], ['3', 'D'], ['4', 'D'], ['4', 'C'], ['5', 'D'], ['J', 'S'], ['J', 'C']]
```

expected output:

```
[['3D'], ['4D', '4C'], ['5D'], ['JS', 'JC'], ['4D'], ['4C'], ['5D'], ['JS'], ['JC']]
```

Just to reiterate, the aim here is to preserve the concatenated-ness of the card element in the for loop.

Many thanks.

P.S. For those interested, it is a play generator for a card game where single cards and 2+ of a number can be played

Comment: Could you store the cards as tuples to avoid this?

Comment: Creating the list `plays` can be simplified. `from operator import itemgetter` `plays = [list(suit) for rank,suit in groupby(hand, itemgetter(0))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hand = ["3D", "4D", "4C", "5D", "JS", "JC"]

from itertools import groupby 

def generate_plays(hand):
    plays = []
    for rank,suit in groupby(hand, lambda f: f[0]):
        plays.append(list(suit))
    for card in hand:
        if [card] not in plays:       #redundant due to list nesting
            plays.append([card])       #problematic code in question
    return plays

print generate_plays(hand)
```